# Proper dot points in the same font inside \entry

Tags: fonts, formatting, itemize, enumitem

I'm trying to make a resume and list out my experiences right now. But I couldn't figure out how to get propper looking dot points inside my entrylist. I have tried $\cdot$, but i couldn't add multiple lines. Enumerate just screws up the next \entry. Here is my [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/tyqdfqqbskqd), and here is the section im having trouble with. Thanks!

```
\documentclass[9pt]{developercv}
\begin{document}


\cvsect{Education}

\begin{entrylist}


    \entry
        {2007 -- 2013}
        {Bachelor's Degree}
        {A University Name}
        {\lorem}

    \entry
        {20013 -- 2024}
        {Masters's Degree}
        {A University Name}
        {$\cdot$ dot points}
        {$\cdot$ dot points}
% screwes up the next line

    \entry
        {2024 -- 2026}
        {PHD}
        {A University Name}
        {$\cdot$ dot points}

\end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

edit: minimum sample

Comment: Welcome! Please post a complete minimal working example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Sure, lemme just fix this